# Bootstrap justify-content not working with form

Tags: html, css, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I have an input form that's meant to capture twitter handles. I simply want to center the input and submit buttons in the center of the page, but for some reason I can't get it to work with me. Here's the relevant snippet of CSS/HTML (also note, I'm using Bootstrap & ASP.NET)

```
<form asp-action="GetTwitterHandle">
    <div class="submitView">
        <input name="UserHandle" class="form-control" placeholder='&#64Example_User'/>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Get Stats" />
    </div>
</form>
```

```
.submitView {
    border: 1px solid orange;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set `height: 100vh;` in the submitView class. it will align the item horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you want something like this... remove  width: 50% and add height: 100vh;

If it's not helping, let me know by commenting.

Comment: I only have it in there because without it the text box spans nearly the whole page. Although it doesn't do that in JSFiddle so perhaps it's something with another action I'm missing?

Comment: I just did the same thing in JSfiddle. It's working. This code is a small piece, right? Maybe something else is causing the problem.